# custom deleget not responding ToSelector

Tags: ios, iphone, methods, delegates, delegation

Following is my code, there is no error but selector is not responding.

Code in **ExampleTableviewSubProductDetail.h**

```
@protocol EnterAmountDelegate <NSObject>

 -(void)titlechange:(NSInteger)amount;

@end

@class ASIFormDataRequest;
@interface ExampleTableviewSubProductDetail :  UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <EnterAmountDelegate>delegate;
```

Code in **ExampleTableviewSubProductDetail.m**

```
  @implementation ExampleTableviewSubProductDetail
  @synthesize delegate;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(titlechange:)])
{
    //send the delegate function with the amount entered by the user
    [delegate titlechange:20];
}
```

code in **HostProductdetailViewController.h**

```
 #import "ViewPagerController.h"
 #import "ExampleTableviewSubProductDetail.h"

 @interface HostProductdetailViewController :  ViewPagerController <ViewPagerDataSource, ViewPagerDelegate, EnterAmountDelegate>
{
}
```

code in **HostProductdetailViewController.m**

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.dataSource = self;
self.delegate = self;

 }
 -(void)titlechange:(NSInteger)amount
  {
   NSLog(@"sdfsf");
  }
```

In the viewwillapper following Line always return false

```
 if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(titlechange:)])
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: What is the class hierarchy of `ViewPagerController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When pushing from HostProductdetailViewController to ExampleTableviewSubProductDetail you need to set the exampleTableviewSubProductDetail.delegate = self

Comment: Thanks @krisJones This worked.... It would be great if you can give some explanation.... :)

Comment: You need to set the exampleTableviewSubProductDetail.delegate to self so the classes delegate is set, otherwise the delegate will not be set. Think of it as setting a variable. As the HostProductdetailViewController conforms to the EnterAmountDelegate, we can set that controller to be the exampleTableviewSubProductDetail delegate. Hope this explains it. http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns in the How to Use the Delegate Pattern gives a good explanation

Answer (score 1):

As I see some other potentially dangerous things in your code try checking this example. It consists of 2 simple classes which are connected via delegate. Watch out for strong references on delegates as this code of yours will produce a retain cycle and cause a memory leak.

Protocol:

```
// defining a custom protocol
@protocol PingProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)didPing;
@end
```

Ping class:

```
//
// This class will be able to send notifications via delegate for the protocol PingProtocol
// Any object that implements PingProtocol will be able to assign itself to the delegate property and will be notified to all protocol methods
//
@interface PingClass : NSObject

// The listener object that implements PingProtocol
// Note this should be weak or there will a retain cycle
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PingProtocol> delegate;

@end

@implementation PingClass

// Some event that happens will check if the delegate actually implements this method and call it.
// The respondsToSelector is not necessary in this case since the method is not optional though.
- (void)onEvent:(id)sender
{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didPing)])
    {
        [self.delegate didPing];
    }
}

// Will create a timer which will call onEvent: every second.
// Note there should be some way to invalidate the timer as this will cause a memory leak for the PingClass
- (void)startPing
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(onEvent:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

@end
```

Listener:

```
//
// This class will listen to PingProtocol methods.
// It will need to implement all non-optional methods defined by PingProtocol
//
@interface ListenerClass : NSObject<PingProtocol>

@property (nonatomic, strong) PingClass *someClass;

@end

@implementation ListenerClass

// will create a PingClass object and asign itself as a delegate to start listening to delegate methods
- (void)startListening
{
    self.someClass = [[PingClass alloc] init];
    self.someClass.delegate = self;
    [self.someClass startPing];
}
// A protocol method
- (void)didPing
{
    NSLog(@"Ping");
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and effort... I will consider this changes in my code... :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing `self`:

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(titlechange:)])
```

You need to watch out for these things. The delegate in your case is closer to a function pointer then an actual object. You might also be able access it via `_delegate` as well.

Comment: Then set the breakpoint there and log what is your delegate. Write in the consol "po [delegate class]" when on breakpoint. Also check if the delegate is actually present (not nil).